# How to draw a 4x4 grid using square sprites using libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d

Hi want to develop a game puzzle game similar to flow free. However i want to use square sprites to create the grid can anyone show me how to position the square sprites to make it look similar to 4 x 4 grid. The square sprites are 100 x 100.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into `Tilemaps`. If you have a single square sprite with it's borders a different color we could tile this next to each other to create a grid.

We can draw your 100x100 tiles next to each other in a 4x4 grid by using a double loop.

```
    tileWidth = 100;
    tileHeight = 100;
    gridWidth = 4;
    gridHeight = 4;

    for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
        {
            //Draw function (sprite, position X, position Y)
            draw(tileTexture, x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but how do you center the 4x4 grids ?

Comment: What do you mean by center? `4 * 100 = 400` so the center lies `X:200` and `Y:200` from where you start drawing. You could offset your drawing or move the camera in position.

Comment: I want my grids to be drawn and position like the one in the LINK

https://lh3.ggpht.com/QPYySkEBPEBtIWo0xFucU5Sv2DFtdXkhct0mZjQMsfdcqn76vrI_WyQ2NxnC6HpoUdI=h900